# How to use same texmf directory with different operating systems?

Tags: installing

For some reasons I have to install a 64-bit RPM based Linux (Fedora or SUSE) beside a 32-bit Debian-based Linux (Ubuntu or Arch) on my machine.

I want to use same TeXLive Installation from both OSs. Am I able to introduce the texmf directory of Ubuntu (`/usr/local/.../texmf-dist`?) to Fedora or vice versa? How?

Comment: Did you installed TeXLive manually or is it the one provided by Fedora or SuSE distribution? A manually installed TeXLive would be *much* easier to share.

Comment: @Martin: I installed from `.iso` image.

Comment: You mean the TeXLive ISO image?

Comment: @Martin: yes :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to share the `texmf-dist` directory between different OSs. If you install TeXLive manually using the official installer than there shouldn't be a problem. However, if you install it using the Linux packages provided by the distributions problems might occur when one wants to update the LaTeX packages there. Only sharing `texmf-dist` seems to be a good idea so that the binaries are kept separated. However, this is not really necessary because 32-bit and 64-bit are AFAIK kept separately in different subfolders of `bin/`.

You need to install TeXLive on one distribution. Then you mount the partition where `/usr/local` is located under the other distribution (e.g. to `/mount/otherdistri`) and either create an symbolic link from `/usr/local/.../texmf-dist` to `/mount/otherdistri/usr/local/.../texmf-dist` or use

```
mount --bind /mount/otherdistri/usr/local/.../texmf-dist /usr/local/.../texmf-dist
```

to virtually mount the directory there. You can place these mount instructions into the `/etc/fstab` config file.